# Is there an procedure in MySQL similar to sp_executesql in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I would like to make dynamic queries in within my procedure.
SQL Server has neat sp_executesql  procedure for such tasks, is there anything in MySQL which can help me to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: Is [this](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK there is nothing exactly same. However, you can use a prepared statement, like:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
mysql> SET @a = 3;
mysql> SET @b = 4;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
+------------+
| hypotenuse |
+------------+
|          5 |
+------------+
mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Copied from here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 3):

You will probably have to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for that purpose using MySQL:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO tbl (a) VALUES (?)';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

...
SET @param = 'hello';
EXECUTE stmt USING @param;
...

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```